# How to Format a String with Leading Zeroes to Decimal in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to parse a string such that the amount field is formatted with 2 decimal places.  The original data provides 2 decimal place accuracy.  However, the amount field in the data file is 16 characters long with leading zeroes.  For example:

```
0000000000407981
```

should convert to 4079.81.
I've tried the following in my select statement:

```
format((substring([Column 0],51,16)/100), '.00') as CheckAmount,
```

This produces an amount with 2 decimal places but rounds to the nearest whole dollar.  I'm using SQL Server 2016.

How do I modify my statement to ensure the CheckAmount is formatted with 2 decimal point accuracy and contains an accurate value?

Update:  I attempted to convert to integer as follows:

```
format(convert(int, (substring([Column 0],51,16)/100.0)), '.00') as CheckAmount,
```

Unfortunately, I receive an error stating:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

How should I remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with the following code snippet:

```
CAST((CAST(substring([Column 0],51,16) as int)/100.0) as decimal(18,2)) as CheckAmount,
```

Hope this helps anyone who might need to accomplish a similar task.

Answer (score 1):

The divide by 100 does an *integer division*. You do not get decimal numbers. Dividing by 100.0 will.

```
declare @num nvarchar(20) = '0000000000407981';

select convert(bigint, @num)/100.0;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7fcdc050dbc393d91c1e3950311c9d7a)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Please see my update with new error after implementing your syntax.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: You have large numbers in your table, too big for an `int`. Answer updated to use `bigint`. [T-SQL data type documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql)

Comment: @SidC, Your conversion `substring([Column 0],51,16)/100` also contains an _implicit_ conversion. The `substring([Column 0],51,16)` is a string value, but SQL tries to convert it to `numeric` to do the division... Make the cast explicit `convert(bigint, substring([Column 0],51,16))`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested change to bigint.  I made the change but error persists.  I'll review the data type URL, suggestions welcomed.  Thanks again!

Comment: @SidC, Did you also resolve the implicit conversion I described above? If so, please add the troublesome value as a sample to your question. We will need the specific value of `substring([Column 0],51,16)` that is giving you troubles. Any chance this data contains alphanumeric characters instead of just numbers? Have a look at [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a3dd15ab36919df17feccf5a28cead8) on how to find the troubling values.